# how to set correct cookies in express?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
    app.use(cookieParser());    
    app.use(cors(corsOptions))
    app.use('/', cors(), function(req, res){
      res.cookie('test', 'hallo', { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10, httpOnly: 
   true });
  res.end('ok')
})
```

**res.cookie('test', 'hallo', { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 10, httpOnly:
true });** 
why I get api set cookies not work ?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to the lower part of your screenshot, the `set-cookie` header is in the response from http://localhost:3002, but according to the upper part you look for it in http://localhost:8080, that is, in the wrong origin.

The browser tools only display cookies from the origin(s) of the currently loaded HTML page.

Comment: thanks your answer!Now I know why I can't get cookies! because backend write when login and go to other page, so I can't get, but I can get now.Bacause He take off next to page!