# Setting an cookie from an third-party API

Tags: vue.js, express, cookies, cross-domain

I have an ExpressJS API, and a Vue front-end.
On the front-end I make the API call to the back-end. The front-end is hosted on (example) q.front.com and the backend on x.back.dev. They both have HTTPS connections. Now how can I set an cookie and receive the cookie on the API again?

I have tried set-cookie: set-cookie: fatham=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MzYzMzE0MTcsImlhdCI6MTYzMzczOTQxNzc1NiwianRpIjoiYzllYzdkMWEtYzAwZS00OWU1LTkyMTQtMTljYjU5ZjhkMmJjIiwiaXNzIjoiVk9MVElBQyIsInN1YiI6ImluZm9AZG9ycHN3YWFyZC5jb20ifQ.6z0m3tGo3z7q4L35V0hdyqXC_ZjhtJJC0pktcUwQOLg; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None

```
set-cookie: fatham=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE2MzYzMzE0MTcsImlhdCI6MTYzMzczOTQxNzc1NiwianRpIjoiYzllYzdkMWEtYzAwZS00OWU1LTkyMTQtMTljYjU5ZjhkMmJjIiwiaXNzIjoiVk9MVElBQyIsInN1YiI6ImluZm9AZG9ycHN3YWFyZC5jb20ifQ.6z0m3tGo3z7q4L35V0hdyqXC_ZjhtJJC0pktcUwQOLg;SameSite=None; Secure;Domain=x.back.dev;path=/;
```

But there isn't a cookie being set at any of the domains...

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69448732/how-to-set-correct-cookies-in-express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a simple example of how u do that

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
  const d = new Date();
  d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  let expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  let name = cname + "=";
  let ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for(let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
  }
  return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
  let user = getCookie("username");
  if (user != "") {
    alert("Welcome again " + user);
  } else {
    user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
    if (user != "" && user != null) {
      setCookie("username", user, 365);
    }
  }
}
```